# Jquery multiple select cells in table row using expressions in filter method

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I'm wondering how i can do these things using jquery **filter method**:

Select cell 1 to 4 and 6 to 8 in on table row.

**or**

Select cell 1 and cell 6 to 8 in that table's TR.

I've tested these methods but they weren't useful.

**For the first:  filter('gt(2):lt(4),gt(7):lt(8))'**

**For the second: filter('eq(2),gt(7):lt(8)')**

in code bellow the results may be like (cell number 1 to 8 excluding cell5 for the first) and (cell1 cell 6 cell 7 cell 8 for the second

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="selection">
    <tbody>
        <tr>

            <td>cell1</td>
            <td>cell2</td>
            <td>cell3</td>
            <td>cell4</td>
            <td>cell4</td>
            <td>cell5</td>
            <td>cell6</td>
            <td>cell7</td>
                        <td>cell8</td>
        </tr>   
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you show us your code so far?

Comment: @Lokase I've just put the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jquery filter.

```
// exclude 5th column (zero based indexes)
$(your_selector_to_cels).filter(function(index) { return index != 4; })

// get only column 1, 6, 7, 8
$(your_selector_to_cels).filter(function(index) { return index == 0 || (index >= 5 && index <= 7); })
```

I don't know how hard coded you want to do that, but this is a way to do that.

Comment: I've just edited the question. Is any other way to do that? like this: $(your_selector_to_cels).filter('eq(2),gt(7):lt(8)')?

Comment: @DavidPeterson it is the same thing, I just used a function instead of a selector. In my code, you just need to change the function passed to filter instead of construct a different string.

Answer (score 1):

This could help :

```
$('TABLE TD').slice(1, 9).not(':eq(4)').css({'color': '#f00'});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NNNqF/

Answer (score 1):

You can use this selector:

```
$('#selection tr:eq(0)').find('td:lt(4), td:gt(4):lt(3)')
```

The first part `$('#selection tr:eq(0)')` makes sure you selector only cells from a specific row (in this case, row 0, the first one).

A few notes on part 2:

1. Use `find` to select within the previously returned jQuery object.
2. `gt` and `lt` selectors are zero-index based. So in order to select the first cell, you use `'td:lt(1)` which means "select the `td` with index less than 1". On the same note, to select the last, you have to use `td:gt(8)` which means "select `td` with index greater than 8 (since it's zero based, 10 elements go from 0 to 9, thus 9 is the last).
3. You can have multiple selectors separated by `,`. So `'td:lt(1), td:gt(8)'` will get you both first and last cells
4. Last but not least, there's an specific behavior when you chain `gt` and `lt`. Notice that to get 6, 7 and 8 the selector is `td:gt(4):lt(3)`. `gt(4)` will get cells with index more than 4 (remember that in a zero-indexed collection, index 5 is the sixth item) and when you chain with `:lt(3)` the indexes are now relative to the returned from the previous `gt`, which in the end means you are asking for the next 3 items.

Comment: for knowing better tis concept could you tel me how i can filter the founded result again? something like this: $('#selection tr:eq(0)').find('td:lt(4), td:gt(4):lt(3)').find ('other filtering method') in selected area)

Comment: Use the filter method http://api.jquery.com/filter/ `$('#selection tr:eq(0)').find('td:lt(4), td:gt(4):lt(3)').filter(...)`